# How To Default The Default Queue When Looking At a View For Queue Items?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have view that returns a filtered sum of Queue Items, which I display on a custom webpage.  It is a hyperlink, so if the user clicks on it, it redirects them to the actual view in CRM.  Since this is an Advanced Find against queue items, there is a Queue drop down that filters the queue items to a particular view.

[image: Queues I'm a member of]

This is always defaulting to "Queues I'm a member of", but I want it to default to "All Queues"

[image: All Queues]

The html shows that there is a default View Id being provided:

```html
<select name="crmQueueSelector" class="ms-crm-SelectBox " id="crmQueueSelector" onchange="OnQueueChange(this);" defaultselected="{436e2293-da8f-4ef9-a1e6-fff25a5beb22}">... </select>
```

Presumably setting that value would change the defaulted queue filter.  Is there any way to set that value?

It is really confusing to our end users when they see they have 48 items, but when they click on it, only 10 are showing since it's only their queues.  Any way to set this?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: I'd also love to see an answer to this.

Comment: Me 3.  I was unable to implement thus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned on server side tracing to see what calls were being made, and the only two calls that are being performed during the load of the view, are two calls to `RetrieveUserQueues`.  The first is for Non-public queues available to the user, then public queues available to the user.  The result of the calls do not include the "All Queues", or "Queues I'm a Member of" options listed in the drop down.  Therefore, there must be some javascript that is taking the results, and adding in the other Queue options to the drop down list, and since you can't attach JavaScript to the View Screen before it loads, this value can't be defaulted.